# Stripe Android POS integration card scanner

Tags: stripe-payments

I bought an Android POS from Alibaba (Aisino A90), I finished all Stripe steps until the point I can collect payment as seen in the image below, and it works fine.
Now, I need to swipe the card on my device and make payment, I found Stripe terminal (but it looks like it only works with Stripe devices).
I was wondering if there are examples of stripe integration with external card scanners (like mine) if anyone can put me in the right direction to use Stripe with my POS, that would be great.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use Stripe Terminal with 3rd-party readers as Stripe Terminal works only with pre-certified card [readers](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-reader).

Comment: Are you aware of any workaround?